# jquery, can't change a div width to the window width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to make 3 div that scroll left and right inside a other div in overflow.
And I did this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.0/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        margin-right: -300px;
    }
    .content-container {
        top: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 1340px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content-container" id="content-container-id">
        <div class="container" id="container-search"></div>
        <div class="container" id="container-sim"></div>
        <div class="container" id="container-forum"></div>

        <script>
        $("#content-container-id")
            .css("height", ($(window).height() - 150) + "px");

        $("#content-container-id")
            .css("width", $(window).width());

        $("#container-search")
            .css("width", $(window).width());

        $("#container-search")
            .css("height", ($(window).height() - 170) + "px");

        $("#container-search")
            .css('left', $(window).width());

        $("#container-sim")
            .css("width", $(window).width());

        $("#container-sim")
            .css("height", ($(window).height() - 170) + "px");

        $('#container-forum')
             .css('left', windowWidth * 2 + "px");

        $("#container-forum")
             .css("width", $(window).width());

        $("#container-forum")
             .css("height", ($(window).height() - 170) + "px");

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the `#container-search`, `#container-sim`, `#container-forum`, don't use all the window space and just a bit, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could  you please describe only minimal problem? Not just paste whole page and ask for help. What did you tried already?

Comment: I tried to make 3 div that scroll left a right inside a other div that as the style of overflow use the code above. But the divs inside the overflow div does not use all of the window space, when I tried to code that in jquery

Comment: Don't know if it's the cause of the problem but you're missing the closing div for #content-container-id

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
$('#container-forum').css('left', windowWidth * 2 + "px");
```

`windowWidth` is not a declared variable. You need to change this to:

```
$('#container-forum').css('left', $(window).width() * 2 + "px");
```

All 3 divs are now displaying in your `#content-container-id`. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/fyb5zxto/

I've coloured the divs to make it a bit easier to see what's happening. You can remove this colouring. I also added in the missing closing div for the `#content-container-id`